# Upgrade Xcode6 Project from Beta to GM

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Is there anyway to upgrade a xcode Beta project to the GM, as the GM use some new files etc like the LaunchScreen.xib or is the only way to handle this create a new project and copy paste alle files etc?

Answer (score 0):

The Beta version of Xcode shouldn't be used to create any new project, it's just for **testing** ...

So I think you will need to copy the files which you worked on, from the old project, and move them to the new project which is created in the Xcode 6 GM

Hope this will help you ..